# Python script raising ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll

I am using Python 3.10.4 and wanted to use the module rasterio, so I downloaded it in the CMD window as per below commands

```
C:\Python10\Scripts>pip install GDAL-3.4.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
C:\Python10\Scripts>pip install rasterio-1.2.10-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
```

They successfully installed, and I tried to run a script,

```
import rasterio

xyz = 'C:/test/test.xyz'

dataset = rasterio.open(xyz)
dataset.bounds
```

but now I'm getting the following errors:

```
ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\gdal_BAG.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\gdal_BAG.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\gdal_FITS.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\gdal_FITS.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\gdal_GMT.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\gdal_GMT.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\gdal_HDF4.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\gdal_HDF4.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\gdal_HDF4Image.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\gdal_HDF4Image.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\gdal_HDF5.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\gdal_HDF5.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\gdal_HDF5Image.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\gdal_HDF5Image.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\gdal_KEA.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\gdal_KEA.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\gdal_netCDF.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\gdal_netCDF.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

All of the `.dll` files are located within the folder stated, so why can't they be loaded?

Comment: Please post your Python code - we can't help you if we can't see what you're doing

Comment: @JRiggles Apologies, I've included it now

Comment: Hmm...I can't immediately see anything wrong. Do you have any other versions of Python on your system? And as a general 'best practice' note, consider opening your file in a [context manager](https://www.pythontutorial.net/advanced-python/python-context-managers/) like they show [here](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)